# FTP-client software with auto-resume for downloads and uploads

Tags: windows, ftp

I face internet time-outs often and my ftp client just abandons the file upload/download mid-way. Is there a client that supports auto-resume for upload and download of files?

The software can be free or paid I don't mind. My OS is Windows 7

Comment: Don't forget the FTP server also has to be one that supports resumption of downloads (or uploads)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/)

> Ability to resume Uploads/Downloads (if the server supports it)